# How to adjust the Bluetooth sensitivity of my device programmally

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

As shown in the picture, there is a function to set Bluetooth sensitivity in my application. I'd like to know how to set Bluetooth sensitivity as a program on my device.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it in C or Java I'm sure theres a library thats already supported that would give you an external API to control your bluetooth application.

Just from a quick search, this is probably what you're looking for:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#java